# Add new form row before table and have "enter" go between rows

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to figure out how I would get this script to add a row BEFORE the first table row, as well as allow the "enter" key to cycle between cells. Here is what I have so far, that adds a row AFTER each row

```
var i=$('table tr').length+1;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    addNewRow();
});

$(document).on('keypress', ".addNewRow", function(e){
    var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(keyCode == 9 ) addNewRow();
});

var addNewRow = function(id){
    html = '<tr id="tr_'+i+'">';
    html += '<td><input class="case" id="caseNo_'+i+'" type="checkbox"/></td>';
    html += '<td class="prod_c"><input type="text" data-type="product" name="data[product]['+i+'][product_id]" id="product_'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">';
    html +='</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail]['+i+'][added]" id="added_1'+i+'" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
    html += '</select></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    if( typeof id !== "undefined"){
        $('#tr_'+id).after(html);
    }else{
        $('table').append(html);
    }
     console.log(id);

    $('#caseNo_'+i).focus();

    i++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "append", Use "prepend" which will solve the issue

```
$('table').prepend(html);
```

Comment: NM, fixed, turns out I cant spell prepend :P

Comment: Do you know how I can alter to allow "enter" to cycle between cells?

Comment: Do you mean  adding a new row when clicking "enter"?

Comment: no, moving between fields when i hit enter, say i have a product1, product2, product 3 field - I want it to move from editing product 1, to product 2 when hitting enter, and so on

Comment: Right now, enter just submits the form, I only want the form submitted when the user clicks the "submit form" button, and I want enter to cycle between fields

Comment: For that, you have to check for keypress 13 and write trigger focus of next row, if the control is in one of the rows

Comment: I am sorry, can you demonstrate?  I am mainly into php, and a friend helped me out with the above code